# Equation of a plane given only normal vector to it

Tags: linear-algebra

How to get the equation of a plane in 3D given only normal vector to it?

Say normal vector is [1,1,1]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't given a point? The normal vector fixes its orientation, but not its position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the normal vector is $[a,b,c]$, then the plane will be of the form

$$ax + by + cz = d$$

for some $d$. If $d=0$ then the plane goes through the origin. If you're provided a point, then you can substitute the point to solve for $d$. In your example, the plane would be $x+y+z=d$, but we don't have enough information to find $d$.

We can also write this more compactly with vectors: if the normal is $\Bbb n$, then the plane is of the form $$\Bbb n \cdot \Bbb x = d.$$

Comment: Thank you. I asked this to help myself with this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429329/how-to-construct-a-hyperplane-classifier-in-3d-to-cut-off-one-corner-of-a-cube/2429392#2429392     but it does not seem to help.   I thought that point would be [1,1,1] and normal vector is [1,1,1]. But what I get does not satisfy the answer... I am probably confusing something really badly

Comment: @YohanRoth You're welcome! Incidentally, you could try drawing some lines in $\Bbb R^2$ to see a pattern: for example, draw $5x+y = 0$ and then find its normal line.

Comment: @YohanRoth For the problem you mention, since you are given the point $[1,1,1]$, then you can substitute this into $x+y+z=d$ to find $d$:
$$1+1+1=d,$$
so $d=3$ and the equation will be $x+y+z=3$.